# How do I retrieve the value of an Entry widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm using the following code to try and get the content of the entry/input box to be printed when I click the submit button, however, nothing seems to happen.

```
def submit_answer(response):
    print(response)


def get_answer():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()

    contentFrame = Tkinter.Frame(root)

    entryWidget = Tkinter.Entry(contentFrame)
    entryWidget['width'] = 50
    entryWidget.pack()

    contentFrame.pack()

    button = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Submit', command=submit_answer(entryWidget.get()))
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Well idk if this helps at all but i having a similar problem with tkinter events, and i solved it by by putting the "command" variable inside of a lambda statement: button = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Submit', command= **lambda:** submit_answer(entryWidget.get()))

Answer (score 1):

ValekHalfHeart's comment is correct.

When you do `command=submit_answer(entryWidget.get()))` it executes `submit(entryWidget.get())` once, and then uses the result of that function (probably `None`) as the click event. This is not what you want.

When you wrap it in a `lambda`, the function is executed each time you click. For it to work, you should have `command=lambda:submit_answer(entryWidget.get())`